# Converting path nodes text file to graph tree

Tags: image, graph, tree, treeview, rendering

I am looking for a software that can take a text file of nodes paths of my tree and will draw the vertical representation of the full tree.
e.g. if the text file contains the following description of my tree:

ROOT

ROOT\NodeA

ROOT\NodeA\NodeB

ROOT\NodeA\NodeB\Leaf01

ROOT\NodeA\NodeB\Leaf02

ROOT\NodeA\NodeC

ROOT\NodeA\NodeC\NodeD

ROOT\NodeA\NodeC\NodeD\Leaf03

ROOT\NodeA\NodeC\NodeD\Leaf04

ROOT\NodeA\NodeC\Leaf05

ROOT\Leaf06

I would like the program simply generates the following:

[Output example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XW4H1.jpg)

I can change, a little, the text file format if needed (because is generated by a Visual Basic code using the treeview control) to another format. e.g. replacing "\" with commas or replacing full paths with TAB
And it's fine to have as output an image (in any format) or just a temporary visualization that would allow me to make a simple screenshot (CTRL+PRINT).

I wonder why I can't find what I am looking for neither by long google searches.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I've tested many software last days, but none matches my need.

This print a horizontal view that I would appreciate anyway, but it needs different input format:
https://planetcalc.com/8443/

This one is too powerful but also sophisticated and heavy to install:
https://orange.biolab.si/screenshots/

I also seen many easy software but that was just for assisted diagrams design where you have to draw by yourself your chart  from templates (without input data).

Comment: I also tryed a couple of online software for charts builder but I was not able to run them because they need a column separated csv file where each column have his header name, and I am not able to convert (if it's possible) my input to that one.

Finally I changed my mind because for this job the file format "JSON" could help for the rendering of my graph, but my search turned without nice results again.

Comment: If you're asking for software recommendations, that is [off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for stackoverflow! (The same link can tell you what is on-topic for this site)

Comment: utility recomendations maybe...I am writing a code and I need the structure of the tree that my code is building. I can generate the output I shown on my question and a some more forms. But I have non skills in image manipulations.  By the way I found a very similar discussione [here](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/35166/software-for-automaticaly-create-hierarchical-treemap-from-a-table) but I can't use Phyton language  if I am off topic, never mind. This question can be closed right now.